# Trying to get the biggest number

Tags: c

I'm trying to receive the biggest number from the int array but it's not working so well for me.

```
for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
    {
        printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c+'a',count[c]);
        if(count[c] > tempcount1)
            {
                temp=count[c];
            }
        tempcount1=count[c];
    }
    printf("%d",temp);
```

`tempcount1` is set to 0 at the start of the program. Does anyone knows where the problem is in my code?

Comment: Are you supposed to compare tempcount1 and then update temp?

Comment: You appear to have two seperate variables, `temp` and `tempcount1`, when you only want one.  Get rid of `temp=count[c];` and move `tempcount1=count[c];` inside the if statement.  Then print `tempcount1` at the end rather than `temp`.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to assign ```tempcount1``` inside if statement and nowhere else? What is ```temp``` for?

Comment: @John Coleman They can not be negative by the definition. As I have understood it is an array of character frequencies of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are juggling two variables which hold the max count. `tempcount1` which you compare with is always updated even if the current count is not greater.

```
for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
    {
        printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c+'a',count[c]);
        if(count[c] > tempcount1)
            {
                temp=count[c];
            }
        tempcount1=count[c];
    }
    printf("%d",temp);
```

Here is advised:

```
int max = 0;
for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
{
    printf("'%c' occurs %d times in the entered string.\n", c+'a', count[c]);
    if(count[c] > max)
        max = count[c];
}
printf("Max = %d\n", max);
```